# What's the difference between object and variable?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm confused.. what's the difference between `SQLConnection connection=new SQLConnection();` and `SQLConnection connection;`? what's the situation I should use one of both?

Answer (score 1):

First one: `SQLConnection connection=new SQLConnection();` is variable declaration and initialization at the same time (Eager Initialization) but the later part `SQLConnection connection;` is just the variable declaration since you have decided to initialize it sometime later when it's actually needed to create a `SQLConnection` instance.

You should be using the later one `SQLConnection connection;` if you want to declare it at class level as a global connection variable which say then can be used by multiple methods / event handler/.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not clear for me, why I should use objects ? may I create many variables:SQLConnection connection1,SQLConnection connection2 ...etc then I can access methods and properties of SQLConnection class via them.